# Spliting and storing string in an array php

Tags: php

I have a string

```
$descr = "Hello this is a test string";
```

What I am trying to do is to split the string and store each word which is separated using space into separate array index in PHP. Should I use

```
$myarray = preg_split("[\s]",$descr);
```

Expected outcome :

```
$myarray(1) : hello
$myarray(2) : this
$myarray(3) : is
$myarray(4) : a
$myarray(5) : test
$myarray(6) : string
```

Each number denotes array index

Comment: The code you posted works fine too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting up a string in PHP with every blank space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020202/splitting-up-a-string-in-php-with-every-blank-space)

Comment: I agree with @localheinz the currently accepted answer does not show best practice because it is calling `strtolower()` on every iteration of `$myarray` -- this is not optimal.  Please have a look at my answer and perhaps provide one or two more sample strings in your question so that we can see any differences in string structure (capitalization and punctuation) because these points will impact the correct method for your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) like below:-

```
$myarray = explode(' ', $descr);
print_r($myarray);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/847916

***To re-index and lowercase each word in*** your array do like this:-

```
<?php

$descr = "Hello this is a test string";

$myarray = explode(' ', $descr);

$myarray = array_map('strtolower',array_combine(range(1, count($myarray)), array_values($myarray)));
print_r($myarray);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/847960

To get ***how many elements*** are there in the array:-

```
echo count($myarray);
```

Comment: Why not invoke `strtolower()` before `explode()`ing the string?

Comment: Attention to detail is king.

Comment: @localheinz  please leave me buddy :):). There are n number of solution for a single question. You can go with any-way

Answer (score 2):

```
$descr = "Hello this is a test string";
$myarray = explode(' ', $descr);
```

Will produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => this
    [2] => is
    [3] => a
    [4] => test
    [5] => string
)
```

Use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function which takes the delimiter as the first parameter and the string variable you want to "explode" as the second parameter. Each word separated by the sent delimiter will be an element in the array.

Comment: Gives an error :
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\page\q.php on line 34
Array

Comment: You are doing something wrong. I'm getting the correct output. Show me your code.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best way is to use [str_word_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)

```
print_r(str_word_count($descr , 1));
```

Comment: This counts the words. The question is about getting the words in an array.

Comment: @iblamefish: This function do many things. Please check the tutorial. By passing second argument, it will return an array.

Answer (score 1):

This question is seeking support for a task comprised from 3 separate procedures.

1. How to [split a string on spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020202/splitting-up-a-string-in-php-with-every-blank-space) to generate an array of words?  (The OP has a suboptimal, yet working solution for this part.)

   - Because the pattern is only seeking out "spaces" between words, the pattern could be changed to `/ /`.  This eliminates the check for additional white-space characters beyond just the space.
   - Better/Faster than a regex-based solutions would be to split the string using string functions.

     - `explode(' ',$descr)` would be the most popular and intuitive function call.
     - `str_word_count($descr,1)` as Ravi Hirani pointed out will also work, but is less intuitive.
       **A major benefit to this function is that it seamlessly omits punctuation** --
       for instance, if the the OP's sample string had a period at the end, this function would omit it from the array!
       Furthermore, it is important to note what is considered a "word":

       > For the purpose of this function, 'word' is defined as a locale dependent string containing alphabetic characters, which also may contain, but not start with "'" and "-" characters.
2. How to [generate an indexed array with keys starting from 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33434201/how-to-array-key-start-from-1-instead-of-0)?

   - Bind a generated "keys" array (from 1) to a "values" array:

     - `$words=explode(' ',$descr); array_combine(range(1,count($words)),$words)`
   - Add a temporary value to the front of the indexed array (`[0]`), then remove the element with a function that preserves the array keys.

     - `array_unshift($descr,''); unset($descr[0]);`
     - `array_unshift($descr,''); $descr=array_slice($descr,1,NULL,true);`
3. How to [convert a string to all lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161121/make-a-string-lowercase-where-to-put-it)? (it was hard to find a duplicate -- this a RTM question)

   - `lcfirst($descr)` will work in the OP's test case because only the first letter of the first word is capitalized.
   - `strtolower($descr)` is a more reliable choice as it changes whole strings to lowercase.
   - `mb_strtolower($descr)` if character encoding is relevant.
   - Note: `ucwords()` exists, but `lcwords()` does not.

---

There are so many paths to a correct result for this question.  How do you determine which is the "best" one?  Top priority should be Accuracy.  Next should be Efficiency/Directness.  Followed by some consideration for Readability. Code Brevity is a matter of personal choice and can clash with Readability.

With these considerations in mind, I would recommend these two methods:

> Method #1: (one-liner, 3-functions, no new variables)

```
$descr="Hello this is a test string";
var_export(array_slice(explode(' ',' '.strtolower($descr)),1,null,true));
```

> Method #2: (two-liner, 3-functions, one new variable)

```
$descr="Hello this is a test string";
$array=explode(' ',' '.strtolower($descr));
unset($array[0]);
var_export($array);
```

Method #2 should perform faster than #1 because `unset()` is a "lighter" function than `array_slice()`.

Explanation for #1 : Convert the full input string to lowercase and prepend `$descr` with a blank space. The blank space will cause `explode()` to generate an extra empty element at the start of the output array. `array_slice()` will output generated array starting from the first element (omitting the unwanted first element).

Explanation for #2 : The same as #1 except it purges the first element from generated array using `unset()`.  While this is faster, it must be written on its own line.

Output from either of my methods:

```
array (
  1 => 'hello',
  2 => 'this',
  3 => 'is',
  4 => 'a',
  5 => 'test',
  6 => 'string',
)
```

Related / Near-duplicate:

- [php explode and force array keys to start from 1 and not 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148506/php-explode-and-force-array-keys-to-start-from-1-and-not-0)

Comment: @JohnDoe for a simple question with so many possible right answers, I felt it was important to clarify some of the functions that will serve you and help you (and future readers) to find a refined method.